# aggregate records across dates

Tags: dataset, core-language

Each record in a dataset includes a country name, a year, and observations (e.g., GDP) for that country in that year.  I would like to generate a new dataset with one record per country (so I would now have say GDP1980 and GDP1990 as field names).  Of course I could use `GroupBy` to group by country name, but I think that is not quite the same.  However, if someone can show me a simple syntax in the grouped dataset for manipulating data across years (say, producing GDP1990/GDP1980 for the US and the UK, below), grouping this way may be good enough.

Here is a toy dataset for illustration:

```
Dataset[{
  <|"name" -> "US", "year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>,
  <|"name" -> "US", "year" -> 1990, "GDP" -> 105|>,
  <|"name" -> "UK", "year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>,
  <|"name" -> "UK", "year" -> 1990, "GDP" -> 105|>
  }]
```

Comment: Can you add an expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
GroupBy[
  dataset
, Key["name"]->(StringTemplate["GDP``"][#year]->#GDP&)
, Association
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
GroupBy[{<|"name" -> "US", "year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>, <|
   "name" -> "US", "year" -> 1990, "GDP" -> 105|>, <|"name" -> "UK", 
   "year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>, <|"name" -> "UK", "year" -> 1990, 
   "GDP" -> 105|>}, First -> Rest]

(*

<|"US" -> {<|"year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>, <|"year" -> 1990, 
    "GDP" -> 105|>}, 
 "UK" -> {<|"year" -> 1980, "GDP" -> 100|>, <|"year" -> 1990, 
    "GDP" -> 105|>}|>
*)
```

One record per country, although no renaming of fields.

```
Dataset[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is *not* the best way to do it (it might even not be a *good* way to do it) but I think it is a useful question to answer so this is my take:

```
Dataset[
 With[{names = Union[Normal[ds[All, "name"]]], years = Union[Normal[ds[All, "year"]]]},

  AssociationThread[
   names -> Apply[
     Association,
     Outer[
      With[{name = #1, year = #2},
        Rule @@ Join[{{"GDP", year}}, Normal@Query[All, "GDP"][
          ds[Select[#name == name &] /* Select[#year == year &]]]
         ]
     ] &, names, years, 1], 1]]]]
```

The code returns

[image]

(I'm sure it's obvious, so I'll just note that `ds` in the code, stands for the `Dataset` in the question)